# how to show data in default active tab in laravel 7?

Tags: javascript, laravel

How can I get data on my first active and selected tab, because when I load the page, there is no data on the tab that has been selected as the first alias is blank.

did I miss something?

before
[image: before]

after i click tab
[image: after clicking the tab3]

```
 <div class="menu_content">
 <div class="row text-center">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="menu-filter-area">
             <ul class="menu-filter" id="menu-masonry-sort">
                 @foreach ($category as $category)
                 <li class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}" style="">
                     <a href="{{ $category->name }}" data-target=".{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
                 </li>
                 @endforeach
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
     <div class="menu-items-wrapper col-lg-12">
         <div class="menu-items" id="menu-masonry">
             @foreach ($menu as $menu)
             <div class=" single-menu-list {{ $menu->category_id }}">

                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                         <div class="menu-list-item">
                             <h5>{{ $menu->name }}</h5>
                             <div class="row ">
                                 <div class="col-8">
                                     <p class="item-description">{{ $menu->ingredient  }}</p>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-4">
                                     <p class="price">Rp. {{ number_format($menu->price,2,',','.') }}</p>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
     
                 </div>
             </div>
             @endforeach
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

do i need javascript code?

edited cause fixed

```
// Call to Masonry plugin
    var gallerymasonry = $('#menu-masonry').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.single-menu-list',
        filter: '*',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        transitionDuration: '.6s',
        hiddenStyle: {
            opacity: 0,
            transform: "scale(.85)"
        },
        visibleStyle: {
            opacity: 1,
            transform: "scale(1)"
        }

    });
```

i changed to filter: '*'

Comment: I guess you also need to have the `.active` class on the target tab content `<div class=" single-menu-list {{ $menu->category_id }} active">` corresponding to the 1st tab which is active when the page loads

Comment: @Donkarnash, maybe like this ?
 <div class=" single-menu-list {{ $menu->category_id }} {{ $loop->first ? 'active in' : '' }}">

Comment: Yes, missed the condition `$loop->first?` it should definitely be `<div class=" single-menu-list {{ $menu->category_id }}  {{ $loop->first ? 'active in' : '' }}">`